# Create C# applications which are not framework dependant?

Tags: c#, frameworks

**Is creating applications which don't depend on all of the framework components possible?** I know that you can merge the framework with the app but the whole framework is about 20mb and I'm not sure if all of it is used.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question, what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Recent versions of the framework are much more than 20mb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're asking if you can create a C# application that can be run on a machine without the .NET framework installed, the answer is no.  C# apps (as with other managed apps) need the runtime provided by the framework to run.

***Edit***

Correction.  I was wrong, but with caveats.

See the following link:

http://www.pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/faq/#framework.required

Comment: I have Xenocode Virtualisation Studio but it creates huge files if I embed framework in it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that, your best bet is to switch to Mono.  Mono has a linker.

Comment: Embedding framework is not a problem , I have the required tools to do that

Comment: Ok, so then remove the parts you dont use... whats the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistake to tie one arm behind your back, by limiting the amount of the Framework that you think you need.

If 20mb of disk space is a problem, then you've got some *real* problems.

Comment: Well, that depends on your target platform doesn't it?

Comment: If you're sending an app which is 2mb with embedded framework libraries it will increase the size of an app up to 22mb

Comment: Then get people to install the framework separately, rather than embedding it in your app. Or perhaps make your installer download and install it if it's not present. Keeps the size of your app low (for the people who already have the framework), while still including all required dependencies.

Comment: My story. We had to replace ("upgrade" they called it) SW  for DVB-T transmitter. We went from 8-bit SBC to full fledged SBC with embedded Debian Linux, 512MB RAM, RTC, ARM9, RTC,2 SATA ports (unused) and two SD card slots, all for <150€. We plugged in 1GB SD card, full Debian and Mono 2.4 on it. With 1 or 2 glitches, we developed almost exclusively with VS and .NET and simply deployed to Mono on device, which is hardlybigger than a pack of candies. It runs ASP.NET, SNMP server, SQLite and other stuff. Needs 5V PSU. I really can't see *why* .NET runtime is such a problem on a full blown PC?

Answer (score 1):

Starting at .NET 3.5, you can target the "Client Profile", a smaller subset of the .NET Framework. See the [introduction post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/05/12/visual-studio-2008-and-net-framework-3-5-service-pack-1-beta.aspx) by Scott Guthrie

Answer (score 0):

You could try a linker like the one found [here](http://www.xenocode.com/).  I don't know how well they work, but it is an option.

Comment: It is not a linker, it is a virtualisator and I have it at work but it creates huge files and it makes a sandbox when you run it